# Can you stack clipping masks?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
http://www.psdvault.com/photo-effect/create-dramatic-meteor-and-burning-city-effect-in-photoshop/

In the first part where it says to:
"Add the following image adjustment layers as clipping mask to this sky layer"

I added 4 new image adjustment layers, and made them all clipping masks, like this:
[image]

The values of all the layers are correct, but my image doesn't look like the one in the tutorial at this point.
To my surprise re-arranging the order of the image adjustment layers, even though they're clipping masks, makes a difference to how the image looks.

How am I supposed to know, following that tutorial, how I should arrange my image adjustment layers?

Comment: Add them in the sequence given, each on top of the one before. You have them reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using filters or layer adjustments, the order or operations matter. Unfortunately without the original tutorial PSD file to refer to, it's impossible to say which order your adjustment layers should be in to achieve the same effect as the tutorial.

I should also note that your question would be better phrased as "Does stacking order matter with adjustment layers?"